# url friendly and keeping hierarchy

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hierarchy, friendly-url

I am in the process of converting my urls to friendly urls and I'm struggling a little bit with some of them,

For example Lets say posts and categories,

Post (detail):

```
/post/the-title/10 /* /post.php?id=10 */
```

Posts (list)

```
/posts/  /* /posts.php?what=last */
/posts/?what=top /* /posts.php?what=top */
...
```

But What I'm not so sure how to implement categories, in order to keep the structure of the urls, I would like to acomplish:

```
/posts/category-name/5 /* /posts.php?what=cat&id=5 */
```

But this is how I am re-rewriting my urls (for listing):

```
RewriteRule ^posts/$ posts.php?$1&friendly=1 [QSA]
```

So I believe I should preppend it so the other one doesn't trigger, something like:

```
RewriteRule ^posts/(.+)/(.+) posts.php?what=cat&id=$2&friendly=1
RewriteRule ^posts/$ posts.php?$1&friendly=1 [QSA]
```

So questions, here, are:

1) Is that a way (near) to go? (expecting that url types will change)
2) Will establishing the RewriteRule before the other one asure that it won't end up in a loop?

Any input would be welcome, I'd like to think this through before commiting to a url structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "/post/the-title/10 /* /post.php?id=10 */"

```
RewriteRule ^post/[^/]+/([0-9]+)/?$ /post.php?id=$1&friendly=1 [L,QSA]
```

For "/posts/  /* /posts.php?what=last */"

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^what=
RewriteRule ^posts/?$ posts.php?what=last&friendly=1 [L,QSA]
```

For "/posts/?what=top /* /posts.php?what=top */"

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^what=
RewriteRule ^posts/?$ posts.php?friendly=1 [L,QSA]
```

For "/posts/category-name/5 /* /posts.php?what=cat&id=5 */"

```
RewriteRule ^posts/[^/]+/([0-9]+)/?$ /posts.php?what=cat&id=$1&friendly=1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your anser, so the order doesn't matter?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet The order above is fine, since there's no overlap between the regex patterns.

Comment: Good one @Jon +1. I've fixed the missing `}` in query string. I believe it might be troubling OP with an error.